# Bookmark feature misbehave when hovercard feature is implemented in typescript

Tags: typescript, image, button, bookmarks, onhover

I have typescript components which is working properly like when I clicked the book mark button it will fetch the dashboard and image and description on top of this I added feature hover over that time new feature is working as expected but bookmark is not working and when I clicked entire page is refreshing and not working as expected

I am taking images from the same source bucket may be this cause the issue?

I need both the feature should work when clicked the bookmark button that time it should take dashboard , image and description and when I Hover on the small card that time it should take only the image